# Implementing MultiValue Parameter with Multiple Columns with Python and ArcGIS Desktop?

Tags: arcpy, arcgis-9.3, python-script-tool

I am working on an ArcGIS (9.3) Python script. One of the inputs is a list of features. For each feature, I need to select a corresponding field. Setting the parameter to MultiValue gives a nice table in the UI for all the features being processed. How do I add another column to the MultiValue table to select a field for each feature?

Cross-posted: http://forums.arcgis.com/threads/30907-MultiValue-Parameter-with-Multiple-Columns

Esri's Answer from the ArcGIS forum:

> Unfortunately, the solution for this was implemented just recently for
>   10.1 with ValueTable inputs for script tools. You will need to have two multivalue parameters with some custom validation to make this
>   work for 9.3.1.

Comment: If it is the generation of multivalue choice list you are interested in - I've seen this [Esri blog post](http://blogs.esri.com/esri/arcgis/2012/07/16/generating-a-multivalue-choice-list/) recently, it might be helpful.

Answer (score 2):

I've worked out how to do this albeit in a fairly simple manner.  I wanted to create a multivalue parameter where I add many FeatureLayers and then choose an ID field for each layer. I've got it working but I was unable to work how to make the field a drop down list, so a user has to enter a field name manually. Here is the interface:

[image: Example interface]

If anyone has managed to crack this problem or some guru from ESRI blesses us with their knowledge I would love to find out how to turn my second column (Site ID) into a drop down, listing specific fields. If you want to see an example of this have a look at the [Create TIN](http://resources.arcgis.com/en/help/main/10.2/index.html#//00q90000001v000000) tool.

Anyway to create this interface I create a script tool and added a parameter of type feature layer and set it to a multivalue as shown below.

[image: Initial interface setting]

I then clicked on the Validation tab at the top and then the Edit button. As this parameter is the 6th parameter in my script tool I updated the following code:

```py
def initializeParameters(self):
    """Refine the properties of a tool's parameters.  This method is
    called when the tool is opened."""

    # Get the 6th parameter
    param = self.params[6]
    param.datatype = "Value Table"
    param.columns = [["Feature Layer","Activity Layer"],["Field","Site ID"]]    
    return
```

This resets the interface into the multi column table that I wanted. When you use GetParameterAsText it returns the following using my example:

`pipeline pid;Dredging did`

---

I've done some more research and have created the tool using a python toolbox. It works very well but does have a limitation if you go back and choose another ID. I have posted the code on GeoNet [here](https://geonet.esri.com/docs/DOC-3210).

Answer (score 0):

if you are looking for a drop-down list for the Site ID parameter, you can use a code as the following:

```
 param.filters[1].list = ['pid', 'id']
```

So, you can create a cursor or use another method to read all the fields of the FC and pass them, as a list, to the previous sentence